# How to get main thread to wait on completion of StreamReader in a different class

Tags: windows-phone-7, concurrency, webclient, iostream

I am currently developing an app but fairly new to wp7 development, I have the main process calling to another class that uses a StreamReader to read the contents of a webpage and assign variables. The problem i'm having is that the main process is trying to use the variables before they have been assigned values. Is there any way to make the main process wait until the StreamReader has completed

In the main thread I have:

```
 locationDetails = new LocationResults();
 locationDetails.getResults(addressDetails);
```

then in the LocationResults class

```
public void getResults(String address)
    {
        String addy, tmp;
        if (address[0] == '+')
        {
            tmp = address.Substring(1);
            addy = baseAddress + tmp + "&sensor=false";
        }
        else
            addy = baseAddress + address + "&sensor=false";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(addy));
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);

    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        String tmp;
        var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
        tmp = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
        results = tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time since I worked with WP 7 and .NET but I think the following approach could help:

1. Use the Task Parallel Library to execute the whole getResult-Procedure asynchronous to your main thread.
2. In the task use the WebClient synchronously and than return the read data.
3. Specify a Continuation action via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194793.aspx and pass the TaskScheduler instance of the main thread so it will be synchronized.
4. Place the code of the main thread which affects the result in your continuation action.

EDIT:
I guess the code should look like that:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((adr)-> InvokeGetResult(adr as string), addressDetails)
   .ContinueWith((data) -> HandleDataSynchronousToMainThread(data),
      TaskScheduler.Current);
```

But once again: it has been a very long time since I wrote my last .NET code ...